# passing a json data object from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I has probaly been asked a lot of times and i ve read lots of threads about it, but simple cant figure it out how to pass a json data pbject from php to java script.

I am am trying to get two single-dimensional json data object arrays(?) from a database and merge them into a two dinemsional json data object array which is then further passed to sigma.js for further processing.

Reading data from database:

```
<?php
require 'sort.php';
$db = db();
$rawNodes = $db->select('node', '*', ['ico_id' => $_GET['id']]);
$rawEdges = $db->select("edge", "*", ["ico_id" => $_GET['id']]);

$nodes = array();
foreach ($rawNodes as $node) {
    array_push($out, $node);
}

$edges = array();
foreach ($rawEdges as $edge) {
    array_push($out, $edge);
}

?>
```

now accessing it in Java Script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Transaction Visualization </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {
                max-width: 1200px;
                height: 800px;
                margin: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="build/sigma.min.js"></script>
        <script src="build/plugins/sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>
        <script src="build/plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getData () {
                var gnodes = <?php echo json_encode($nodes); ?>;
                var gedges = <?php echo json_encode($edges); ?>;

                alert(gnodes[0].adress); // <- Doesnt work? Why?

                var g = {nodes: [], edges: []}; //<- i think this sytanx is correct for making a 2 dim json data object array- is it?

                var xpos = 0;
                var ypos = 0;

                var n;

                for (n in gnodes) { //<- Does not iterate through any Elements
                    alert(gnodes[n].adress); //<- Doest work either? Why?
                    xpos = n.block_number - 4400000;
                    ypos += 100;
                    if (ypos > 10000) { ypos = 0 }
                    g.nodes.push(
                        {
                            "id": n.adress,
                            "label": n.adress,
                            "size": 1, //n.size,
                            "x": xpos,
                            "y": ypos
                        }
                    )
                }

                var edgecount = 0;

                var m;
                for (m in gedges) {
                    g.edges.push(
                        {
                            "id": edgecount++,
                            "source": m.node_adress1,
                            "target": m.node_adress2,
                            "label": m.erc20_value,
                            "type": "arrow"
                        }
                    )
                }
                //g.nodes = gnodes; geht nicht benennung nicht passend
                //g.edges = gedges;

                return g;
            }

            function dispGraph() {
                var gdata = getData();
                s = new sigma({
                    graph: gdata,
                    container: 'container',
                    renderer: {
                        container: "container",
                        type: "canvas"
                    },
                    settings: {
                        edgeLabelSize: 'fixed',
                        nodeLabelSize: 'fixed',
                        defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148',
                        maxNodeSize: 15,
                        minNodeSize: 5,
                        minEdgeSize: 4,
                        maxEdgeSize: 4,
                        minArrowSize: 4,
                        //edgeLabelSize: 'fixed',
                        // {string} The opposite power ratio between the font size of the label and
                        // the edge size:
                        // Math.pow(size, -1 / edgeLabelSizePowRatio) * size * defaultEdgeLabelSize
                        edgeLabelSizePowRatio: 1,
                        // {number} The minimum size an edge must have to see its label displayed.
                        edgeLabelThreshold: 1,
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
        <script>dispGraph()</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You simply need to output it to the DOM, with something like `echo`. You can make the output hidden if you want, but it needs to be outputted.

Comment: What does `console.log(gnodes[0])` show? Are you sure the column name is `adress`? That looks like a typo for `address`.

Comment: console.log(gnodes[0])   gives  "undefined  graph.php:23:17"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easy. In the html file (with .php extension):

```
<?php $json = json_encode($data); ?>
<script>
    var json = <?=$json?>;
</script>
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work for me :/. what could i be doeing wrong?

Comment: Check: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0cd5dd7ea2e4d7efb0e1be3fbd27203ae05f466d

Comment: Change `$out` to `$nodes` in `array_push()`

Comment: Thanks you so much! That did the trick. I dont know how i could have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Zheng helped me with the following correcttion

1)

```
Change $out to $nodes in array_push()
```

2)

```
<?php $json = json_encode($data); ?>
<script>
    var json = <?=$json?>;
</script>
```

Thanks everybody for your contribution!